# node.js / postgres... asynchronous problem?

Tags: postgresql, node.js

I have a list of types: ["type1", "type2, "type3"], on which I loop. For each type:
    - create / execute a query to get the items of a the current type
    - run another function when the query if done ( on('end') ).

```
 for ( var i=0; i<types.length; i++ ){
    type = types[i];
    value = "test";
    ...

    // ADD ITEM: QUERY
    var query = client.query(...); // QUERY ITEMS OF A THE CURRENT TYPE

    // ADD ITEM: ERROR CHECKING
    query.on("error", function (err) {
      ...
    });

    with ({ t: type, v: value }) {  // I HAD TO DO THAT SO THAT ALL THE TYPES ARE TAKEN INTO ACCOUNT
      query.on('end', function() {
        my_function(t, v);
      });
    }
  }
```

my_function is like:

```
function my_function(type, value){
   console.log(type + ',' + value);  // CORRECT (I CAN SEE ALL THE TYPES BEEING LISTED)

   // QUERY OTHER STUFF BASED ON THE VALUE OF "type"
   var query = client.query(...);

   // MAIN STUFF
   query.on('row', function(row){
      console.log(type + ',' + value);  // THIS DOES NOT WORK ANYMORE... ONLY THE LAST TYPE IS TAKEN INTO ACCOUNT WHERE I EXPECT TO GET THIS MESSAGE FOR EACH TYPES.
     ...
   }

   // FINALIZE
   query.on('end', function(){
      ...
   }      
}
```

I guess this is linked to asynchronous process... but cannot figure out where the error is.

**UPDATE**

I have updated my loop so it looks like:

```
 for ( var i=0; i<types.length; i++ ){
    type = types[i];
    value = "test";
    ...

    // ADD ITEM: QUERY
    var query = client.query(...); // QUERY ITEMS OF A THE CURRENT TYPE

    // ADD ITEM: ERROR CHECKING
    query.on("error", function (err) {
      ...
    });

    // MAIN STUFF GOES HERE
    (function(t, v) { query.on("end", function() {
      console.log(t + ',' + v); // OK, I CAN SEE THIS DISPLAYED FOR EACH TYPE
      my_function(t, v);
    }); })(type, value);
  }
```

I modified my_function so it looks like:

```
function my_function(type, value){
   console.log(type + ',' + value);  // OK, I CAN SEE THIS DISPLAYED FOR EACH TYPE

   // QUERY OTHER STUFF BASED ON THE VALUE OF "type"
   var query = client.query(...);

   // MAIN STUFF
   (function(t, v) {
     query.on("row", function(row) {
       console.log('TEST:' + t + ',' + v); // KO, I CAN ONLY SEE THIS DISPLAYED FOR ONE TYPE
   }); })(type, value);

   // FINALIZE
   query.on('end', function(){
      ...
   }      
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
with ({ t: type, v: value }) {  // I HAD TO DO THAT SO THAT ALL THE TYPES ARE TAKEN INTO ACCOUNT
      query.on('end', function() {
        my_function(t, v);
      });
    }
```

Is broken. What you want is this

```
query.on("end", my_function.bind(null, type, value));
```

`Function.prototype.bind` allows you to bind parameters to a function.

Never use `with`. An alternative that also works would be :

```
(function(t, v) {
  query.on("end", function() { my_function(t, v); });
})(type, value);
```

Comment: @raynos, thanks a lot. I used the alternative format, it works perfectly. That is not an easy one. Cheers.

Comment: @Luc the only way I can imagine this bug being is if you had say 3 types, and had 3 row events for the last type, and zero row events for the first two.

Comment: @raynos, I have inner function that I did not yet modify with the alternative format. I will do this and let you know. I think it will be ok then :)

Comment: @raynos, because I did not set the inner functions correctly, I think the DB has been corrupted. I'll start again with an empty DB. I guess you're right. Thanks for your answer. Cheers, Luc

Comment: @raynos. Everything is fine now. Thanks for your help.